# displaying all the data of my table in scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, scalar

i am working on sql and here i have a sql statement where i need to store the data of my sql table in scalar variable

i did something like this

```
declare @variable1 as varchar(50)
declare @variable2 as varchar(50)
SELECT @variable1 = tid, @variable2 = empname
FROM trainerdetails
select @variable2 as empname,@variable1 as tid
```

but only one record is being shown in my output

```
empname     tid
test        354
```

what i should do here if i want to store all the data of my table in my scalar variable?

Answer (score 0):

scalar variable  holds only the last part of  data.you will need a table variable

```
declare @tbl table
(
col1 int,
col2 int
)
insert into @tbl
select * from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

A scalar variable, by definition, only holds a single value at a time. So... If you want to fit an entire columns wort of data into one, you'll need to concatenate that data... Usually is the form of a comma separated array.
Something along these lines...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp;

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    PersonName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #temp (ID, PersonName) VALUES 
    (1, 'Mark'), (2, 'Sally'), (3, 'Joe'), (4, 'Tammy'), (5, 'Bob');

SELECT * FROM #temp t;

--========================================

DECLARE 
    @ID VARCHAR(100) = '', 
    @PersonName VARCHAR(1000) = '';

SELECT 
    @ID = CONCAT(@ID, ', ', t.ID),
    @PersonName = CONCAT(@PersonName, ', ', t.PersonName)
FROM 
    #temp t
ORDER BY 
    t.ID;

SELECT 
    ID = STUFF(@ID, 1, 1, ''),
    PersonName = STUFF(@PersonName, 1, 1, '');
```

results...

```
ID              PersonName
--------------- ------------------------------
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5   Mark, Sally, Joe, Tammy, Bob
```

HTH,
Jason